# C++ Cosine works without the std namespace - Why?

Tags: c++, g++, trigonometry

I have a fairly large application and I am working without the std namespace, I noticed I wasn't including std::cos or std::sin yet I am getting the right results. Why?

An example of some cut down code would be:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
//#include <unistd.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    double pi = 4*(atan(1));

    cout << "pi = " << pi << endl
         << "cos(pi) = " << cos(pi) << endl
         << "sin(pi) = " << sin(pi) << endl;



    return 0;
}
```

I have left all the headers in, I am using them all in the main code. The output returns ~3.14, -1 and 1e-16 as expected. Why does this work? cos and sin are in std aren't they?

I'm using the g++ compiler on a remote unix server

Thanks

Comment: Does Mike Seymour's answer help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085916/why-are-some-functions-in-cmath-not-in-the-std-namespace

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, library implementations are allowed to dump names from the C library into the global namespace as well as `std`, and many do. Even worse, in some cases only some overloads are available in the global namespace, leading to unexpected loss of precision if you don't specify the `std` version.

You should always use the `std` versions, but sadly there's no reliable way to enforce that, so you'll just have to tread carefully through this particular minefield.

Comment: The fact that in some cases, only some overloads are available is a good point (that I'd forgotten, although I've been bit by it).

Answer (score 9):

When you include `<cmath>`, all of the functions are declared in
`std::`.  For the C headers, there is also a special rule, which
allows (but doesn't require) the implementation to make them
visible in the global namespace; this is because most 
implementations will simply adapt the C headers, something like:

```
#include <math.h>
namespace std
{
    using ::sin;
    using ::cos;
    // ...
}
```

This is an obvious way of implementing the library without
having to rewrite everything, just to have it in C++, and it
will result in all of the names also being present in the global
namespace.

Formally, this is a C++11 feature; pre-C++11 required that
`<cmath>` only introduce the symbols into `std::`.  Practically,
all, or at least most implementations did something like the
above, and did introduce them, illegally, into the global
namespace, so C++11 changed the standard to reflect reality.