# Work around disregarded constexpr in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2017, constexpr, compile-time-constant

I have this code:

```
constexpr int log2(const unsigned int x) {
    return x < 4 ? 1 : 1 + log2(x / 2);
}

int main() {
    bitset<log2(2)> foo;
    int bar[log2(8)];

    cout << log2(8) << endl;
}
```

This works fine in gcc: https://ideone.com/KooxoS

But when I try on [visual-studio-2017](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2017) I get these errors:

> error C2975: `_Bits`: invalid template argument for `std::bitset`, expected compile-time constant expression
>    note: see declaration of `_Bits`
>    error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
>    note: failure was caused by call of undefined function or one not declared `constexpr`
>    note: see usage of `log2`

Obviously `log2` is `constexpr` so I assume this is just a bug in [visual-studio-2017](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2017). Is there a way I can work around this bug?

Comment: Looks like visual studio issue. Try visual studio 2019, as they are often slightly behind in standard compliance.

Comment: if I rename this to log22 (or Log2) it compiles in VS2017, all i get is `warning C4101: 'bar': unreferenced local variable`, output prints 3. It looks like its picking up a standard lib one that is not constexpr?

Comment: @NathanOliver this is a bad duplicate I can get the same compilation error locally *without* `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Why is it that math functions aren't confined to the `std` namespace?

Comment: @Borgleader Already reopened.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'll leave my comment there in case anyone else is tempted to close it (someone else commented the same thing before and it got removed).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux To make life easier for the implementors they allow the `<cxxxx>` headers to also let the names be in the global space.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Because [the whole situation is an absolute mess](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/02/29/why-cstdlib-is-more-complicated-than-you-might-think/). See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085916/why-are-some-functions-in-cmath-not-in-the-std-namespace

Comment: @NathanOliver I guess I was more wondering where that exception is codified. Edit : Max's link seems to answer that question though.

Comment: @Borgleader Great comment. That was the issue, thank you. I'll accept one of these answers shortly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your project includes the standard `std::log2` function which the compiler confuses with the your `log2` function. This can happen even if you don't `#include <cmath>` because standard headers are allowed to include any other standard headers. This is also another example of `using namespace std;` backfiring.

One solution is to rename your `constexpr` function to something else :

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

constexpr int logTwo(const unsigned int x) {
    return x < 4 ? 1 : 1 + logTwo(x / 2);
}

int main() {
    bitset<logTwo(2)> foo;
    int bar[logTwo(8)];

    cout << logTwo(8) << endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8suBuZ)

Edit : It seems that `using namespace std;` may be unrelated in this case. The standard `log2` function may be available at the global namespace anyway.

Answer (score 3):

> Obviously `log2` is `constexpr`

A function being `constexpr` does not mean it can be always used to compute a compute-time value. When `x >= 4`, you are calling [`std::log2`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log2), which is not `constexpr` itself.

GCC implements them as such as an extension. See [Is it a conforming compiler extension to treat non-constexpr standard library functions as constexpr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744079/is-it-a-conforming-compiler-extension-to-treat-non-constexpr-standard-library-fu)

Comment: I'd also add that the name collision happens because of the using namespace

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot [Allegedly that's not true...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56582631/work-around-disregarded-constexpr-in-visual-studio/56582849?noredirect=1#comment99743457_56582631)

Comment: @MaxLanghof oh yeah, I forgot that math function may also reside in the global namespace