# 'round()' vs 'std::round()' and 'fabs()' vs 'std::fabs()' in C++ / GCC 4.8

Tags: c++11, math, floating-point, g++4.8

By accident I was calling `round()` and `fabs()` instead of `std::round()` and `std::fabs()` and for the largest integer a `long double` can hold without loosing precision there was a difference.

Consider this test program `round.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdint>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::setw;
using std::setprecision;

void print(const char* msg, const long double ld)
{
    cout << msg << setprecision(20) << ld << endl;
}

void test(const long double ld)
{
    const long double ldRound = round(ld);
    const long double ldStdRound = std::round(ld);
    const long double ldFabs = fabs(ld);
    const long double ldStdFabs = std::fabs(ld);

    print("Rounding using 'round()':                     ", ldRound);
    print("Rounding using 'std::round()':                ", ldStdRound);
    print("Absolute value using 'fabs()':                ", ldFabs);
    print("Absolute value using 'std::fabs()':           ", ldStdFabs);
}

int main()
{
    const int maxDigits = std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits;
    const int64_t maxPosInt = 0xffffffffffffffff >> (64 - maxDigits + 1);
    const long double maxPosLongDouble = (long double) maxPosInt;

    cout << setw(20);
    cout << "Max decimal digits in long double:            " << maxDigits << endl;
    cout << "Max positive integer to store in long double: " << maxPosInt << endl;
    print("Corresponding long double:                    ", maxPosLongDouble);

    test(maxPosLongDouble);

    return 0;
}
```

When compiling with `g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36.0.1)`

```
/usr/bin/g++ -std=c++11 round.cpp -o round
```

and then running it, the results are one larger for the non-`std` function compared to the `std` functions:

```
Max decimal digits in long double:            64
Max positive integer to store in long double: 9223372036854775807
Corresponding long double:                    9223372036854775807
Rounding using 'round()':                     9223372036854775808 <== one larger
Rounding using 'std::round()':                9223372036854775807
Absolute value using 'fabs()':                9223372036854775808 <== one larger
Absolute value using 'std::fabs()':           9223372036854775807
```

I get the exact same output (including 64 bits for long double) when I compile for 32 bits using option `-m32`. Looking at the disassembly (using `gbd` on the 32 bit executable) for function `test()` I get:

```
(gdb) disassemble test(long double) 
Dump of assembler code for function _Z4teste:
   0x080488c0 <+0>: push   %ebp
   ...
   0x080488d2 <+18>:    call   0x8048690 <round@plt>
   ...
   0x080488ee <+46>:    call   0x8048b59 <_ZSt5rounde> (demangled: std::round(long double))
   ...
   0x080488ff <+63>:    fabs   
   ...
   0x08048918 <+88>:    call   0x8048b4f <_ZSt4fabse> (demangled: std::fabs(long double))

   ...
   0x080489a4 <+228>:   leave  
   0x080489a5 <+229>:   ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

So it seems different function are called for `round()` and `std::round()`. For `fabs()` a floating point instruction is emitted whereas for `std::fabs()` a function call is emitted.

Can someone explain what is causing this difference and please tell me whether using `std::round()` and `std::fabs()` is the preferred portable choice?

Comment: `::round` and `::fabs` take arguments of type `double`. The C++ versions are overloaded for different data types, so you're not calling the same functions. Try using `::roundl` and `::absl` instead.

Comment: @Praetorian Where does `::round` and `::fabs` (and `::roundl` and `::fabsl`) live. Or rather what have I included to bring them into scope?

Comment: It's implementation specific. Your `cmath` is probably including `math.h` which brings in the C versions of these functions that are defined in the global namespace. There's an answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11086087/241631) that has the relevant standardese.

Comment: Ah, header `<cmath>` includes all the functions from the C header `<math.h>` including the C functions `float roundf(float)`, `double round(double)`, and `long double roundl(long double)` and likewise for `fabs`.

Comment: @Praetorian Would you like to answer to get the credits?

Comment: Nah, feel free to add your own answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Praetorian explains in the comments to the question above, the answer is very simple.

When including the C++ header `<cmath>` GCC brings a number of C++ math functions in the `std` namespace with appropriate overloads, for example:

```
float std::round(float)
double std::round(double)
long double std::round(long double)

float std::fabs(float)
double std::fabs(double)
long double std::fabs(long double)
```

However, it also brings into global scope the corresponding old C functions (same names) and as C does not support overloading these functions are only taking `double` as argument and returning `double`:

```
double round(double)
double fabs(double)
```

Therefore, the calls to `round()` and `fabs()` with no explicit namespace (and no `using namespace std` in the program) are calls to `::round()` and `::fabs()` which are the C functions that will then truncate the argument of type `long double` (64 bit precision) to `double` (53 bit precision) which explains the incorrect results.

Therefore, in C++ always ensure you either prefix with `std::` or have an appropriate `using` declaration. I would recommend to be explicit calling `std::round()` and `std::fabs()`.

**P.S.** In C there are also these functions if you need to handle `float` or `long double`:

```
float roundf(float)
long double roundl(long double)

float fabsf(float)
long double fabsl(long double)
```

**P.P.S.** In C++-14 you can also use `std::abs()` for any floating point type whereas in C++-11 `std::abs()` in only for integer types and `std::fabs()` is for floating point types.